# jQuery Mobile: How to refresh page with dynamic DOM manipulation?

Tags: jquery, dom, mobile

I created a page with jQuery Mobile, and tried to add content dynamically:

```
    $(function () {

        $("#deviceTarget").sortable({
            revert: true
        });

        $("body > div[data-role='page']").append($("<div data-role='header' data-theme='a' data-position='fixed'><h1>Header</h1></div>"));
        $("body > div[data-role='page']").append($("<div data-role='footer' data-theme='a' data-position='fixed'><h1>Footer</h1></div>"));
        $.mobile.activePage.trigger("create");

    });

    $(document).bind('mobileinit',function(){
        $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
        $.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.nativeMenu = false;
      });

    function refreshPage() {
        $.mobile.activePage.trigger("create");
    }
```

But I got the [result](https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/424393_409029825780260_100000197393281_1956109_912724228_n.jpg) (image).

I want to get the [result](https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/64059_409029232446986_100000197393281_1956102_1115844522_n.jpg) (image).

How can I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

all you need to do is to refresh the page

not sure about this code:

```
    $.mobile.activePage.trigger("refresh");
```

but it should work. Otherwise take a look at this [jquerymobile.com article](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/pages/page-scripting.html).

Comment: I tried $.mobile.activePage.trigger("refresh"), but not worked.

Comment: maybe i got your question in the wrong way. Can you explain further? what do you mean by result different to use static layout?

Comment: I added screenshot to indicate my situation.

Comment: This is obviously a jquery refresh problem. Maybe changing "create" to "refresh" could work. Or even calling first "create" and then "refresh".  By the site I linked on the answer, you should use create if you create new  objects, and refresh if you add new items to an existing content, so create in your case should be right. Another thing that comes to my mind is that the jquery css is not properly linked, can you check that out?

Comment: But, I tried "create" and "refresh", both not worked... I just link jQuery mobile's CSS from jQuery CDN source.

Comment: I use .trigger("create") can work on content (e.g. listview), but not work on header and footer.

Comment: in the link i posted in the answer there is a procedure to modify the page DOM BEFORE the creation of the page. Have you tried that one? it looks to me that it is what you are needing.

Comment: I tried, not worked, but it works on non-header/footer element (like listview, grid, button, textbox etc).

Comment: Currently, I decide to ignore "HEADER" and "FOOTER" issue, refresh behavior in content is work fine...