# How can I refresh a page in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, refresh, transition

Whenever I'm navigating back to my index.html from another page on my jQuery Mobile app the css is messed up and requires a refresh to look normal again.  I tried adding `data-ajax="false"`  to all the links to disable any transitions, and it works minimally but once I start navigating around the app and click back to my home it's messed up again.  Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

Thanks :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581653/jquery-mobile-how-to-refresh-page-with-dynamic-dom-manipulation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQM Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

Try `.trigger( "create" );` on the page element

Comment: I tried this <script>
`$("a").trigger( "create" );`
</script>  on every page, but no luck

Comment: not the anchor tag, the page div tag: $("div:jqmData(role='page')").trigger( "create" );

Comment: I got it to work, by reading that info u sent me and just making sure the head was the same on every page.  Thank you.  To do it with the code you sent it should be be put in a js file between `$(document).ready(function() {$("div:jqmData(role='page')").trigger( "create" ); });` correct?  Thanks again.

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html Use $(document).bind('pageinit'), not $(document).ready()

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile Users: 
**Use $(document).bind('pageinit')** !!!!!! **DO NOT USE $(document).ready()**

Thank you @Phill Pafford!

Comment: waw.... very bold enough.